# how to filter the extension in the files directory

Tags: php

```
foreach (new DirectoryIterator($tempFilesPath) as $fileData) 
{ 
$fileName           = $fileData->getFileName();
$fileModifiedTime   = $fileData->getMTime();
}
```

that directory contains .exe, .site like files, so I am not getting filename?

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to escape the .extension files which dont have basename](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20607045/how-to-escape-the-extension-files-which-dont-have-basename)

Answer (score 0):

check this may be use full
..

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/quick-tip-loop-through-folders-with-phps-glob/

**Example :**
If we wish to only print subfolder names, we could use GLOB_ONLYDIR:
view plaincopy to clipboardprint?

```
foreach(glob('userImages/*/TN/*', GLOB_ONLYDIR) as $image)   
{  
    echo "Filename: " . $image . "<br />";      
}
```

which will print:

```
Filename: userImages/username2/TN/subfolder
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$it = new DirectoryIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
  if (!$fileinfo->isDot())
    var_dump($fileinfo->getFilename());
}
```

dot directories could be filtered in the loop by using the `isDot()` method.

```
$it = new FilesystemIterator(dirname(__FILE__));
foreach ($it as $fileinfo) {
  echo $fileinfo->getFilename() . "\n";
}
```

`FilesystemIterator` skips the dot directories